# How to remotely run an application in Windows

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote, remote-connection, winrm

I'm trying to run an application using WinRS:

```
winrs -r:172.19.159.50 -u:my-user -p:my-pass "C:/Program Files/folder/myapp.exe"
```

But I get this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Process is terminated due to
>   StackOverflowException.

I was wondering if there is a way I can solve this or another way to run the app remotely.
The local system is Windows Server 2016 and the remote target is a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Did you try [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)?

Comment: @lx07 it's not working either...what about OpenSSH? is it worth it to try?